# CoffeeScript add several objects to result array each interation

Tags: arrays, reactjs, coffeescript

Need do to smth like this:

```
for word, index in text_array
    React.DOM.span 
      key: index, 
      word
    ' '
```

But in this case CoffeeScript push only last object ' ' into result Array, but i need result array to look like [Object, ' ', Object,' ']

Comment: I think you need to indent your last line

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do here is basically a "flat map"; conceptually it's like this:

- given a results array
- iterate over source array
- each iteration, push N values into results array

You can do it step-by-step like this:

```
results = []
source.forEach (word, idx) ->
  results.push React.DOM({key: index}, word), ''
```

You could also use [Array#flatten](http://underscorejs.org/#flatten) from underscore, which combines nested arrays The `true` argument means "flatten just one level", it's not necessary here but it does convey the intention more specifically.

```
_ = require 'underscore'
results = _.flatten (source.map (word, idx) ->
  [React.DOM.span({key: index}, word), '' ]
), true
```

Either one could be rewritten to use list comprehension, although only the second makes use of the return value:

```
results =[]
for word, index in source
  results.push React.DOM.span({key: index}, word), ''

results = _.flatten (for word, index in source
  [React.DOM.span({key: index}, word), '' ]
), true
```

You could also use [Array#reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce), though I don't think coffeescript list comprehensions support this.

```
results = source.reduce (memo, word, index) ->
  memo.push React.DOM({key: index, word), ''
  memo
, []
```